# Layout Error in android

Tags: android

Hey everyone as I am new to android I try make a calculator app , when I run my app in an android phone it looks fine as:

[image: previous layout]

But when my extraordinary brain thought that why don't use custom text in the buttons so i search the internet for it. But I couldn't use that in my app so in frustration I started from scratch(delete the previous folder of the app) I copy paste all the xml coding into my new file and also able to use custom text. Now my problem is when I run the app in android device it look like this:

[image]

Here is the logcat of app:

```html
01-08 13:51:39.545 6067-6067/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
01-08 13:51:39.775 6067-6067/? D/ActivityThread: handleBindApplication:com.company.calculator
01-08 13:51:39.775 6067-6067/? D/ActivityThread: setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
01-08 13:51:39.775 6067-6067/? D/ActivityThread: setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152
01-08 13:51:39.865 6067-6067/com.company.calculator I/libthemeutils: Theme： libthemeutil.so load success
01-08 13:51:39.875 6067-6067/com.company.calculator W/ActivityThread: Application com.company.calculator can be debugged on port 8100...
01-08 13:51:39.895 6067-6067/com.company.calculator W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
01-08 13:51:39.895 6067-6067/com.company.calculator I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
01-08 13:51:39.895 6067-6067/com.company.calculator W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14516: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
01-08 13:51:39.895 6067-6067/com.company.calculator D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
01-08 13:51:39.895 6067-6067/com.company.calculator I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
01-08 13:51:39.895 6067-6067/com.company.calculator W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14520: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
01-08 13:51:39.895 6067-6067/com.company.calculator D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
01-08 13:51:39.895 6067-6067/com.company.calculator D/dalvikvm: GetMethodID: not returning static method Landroid/os/Process;.getTotalMemory ()J
01-08 13:51:39.895 6067-6067/com.company.calculator D/dalvikvm: GetMethodID: not returning static method Landroid/os/Process;.getFreeMemory ()J
01-08 13:51:40.005 6067-6067/com.company.calculator I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
                                                                  OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.02.07
                                                                  Build Date: 03/30/15 Mon
                                                                  Local Branch: 
                                                                  Remote Branch: 
                                                                  Local Patches: 
                                                                  Reconstruct Branch: 
01-08 13:51:40.035 6067-6067/com.company.calculator D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
01-08 13:51:40.075 6067-6067/com.company.calculator I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@42494250 time:44934479
```

XML file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".calculator_main">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="#E0F2F1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/txt_zero"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:background="#1DE9B6"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView">


            <com.company.calculator.ButtonPlus
                android:id="@+id/button_clear"
                android:layout_width="95dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="@string/button_clear"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

            <com.company.calculator.ButtonPlus
                android:id="@+id/button_sub"
                android:layout_width="95dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="@string/button_sub"
                android:textSize="45sp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_8"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_mul"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_mul" />

            <com.company.calculator.ButtonPlus
                android:id="@+id/button_div"
                android:layout_width="95dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="@string/button_div"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_del" />

            <com.company.calculator.ButtonPlus
                android:id="@+id/button_del"
                android:layout_width="99dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:text="@string/button_del"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_clear"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_clear" />

            <com.company.calculator.ButtonPlus
                android:id="@+id/button_mul"
                android:layout_width="99dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="@string/button_mul"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_div"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_div"
                android:layout_above="@+id/button_sub" />

            <com.company.calculator.ButtonPlus
                android:id="@+id/button_7"
                android:layout_width="95dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="@string/button_7"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button_clear"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <com.company.calculator.ButtonPlus
                android:id="@+id/button_8"
                android:layout_width="95dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="@string/button_8"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button_clear"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_7"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_del"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_del" />

            <com.company.calculator.ButtonPlus
                android:id="@+id/button_9"
                android:layout_width="95dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="@string/button_9"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button_div"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_sub"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button_sub" />

            <com.company.calculator.ButtonPlus
                android:id="@+id/button_equals"
                android:layout_width="95dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/button_equals"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button_4"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_add"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button_add"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

            <com.company.calculator.ButtonPlus
                android:id="@+id/button_4"
                android:layout_width="95dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="@string/button_4"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button_7"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <com.company.calculator.ButtonPlus
                android:id="@+id/button_5"
                android:layout_width="95dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="@string/button_5"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_4"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_4"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_8"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_8" />

            <com.company.calculator.ButtonPlus
                android:id="@+id/button_6"
                android:layout_width="95dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="@string/button_6"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button_sub"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_sub"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button_sub" />

            <com.company.calculator.ButtonPlus
                android:id="@+id/button_1"
                android:layout_width="95dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="@string/button_1"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button_4"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_2"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button_2" />

            <com.company.calculator.ButtonPlus
                android:id="@+id/button_add"
                android:layout_width="95dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="@string/button_add"
                android:textSize="45sp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/button_equals"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_sub"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button_sub" />

            <com.company.calculator.ButtonPlus
                android:id="@+id/button_2"
                android:layout_width="95dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="@string/button_2"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button_6"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_clear"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_5"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_5" />

            <com.company.calculator.ButtonPlus
                android:id="@+id/button_3"
                android:layout_width="95dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="@string/button_3"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button_6"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_equals"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button_equals" />

            <com.company.calculator.ButtonPlus
                android:id="@+id/button_0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:text="@string/button_0"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_dot"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button_dot"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_2"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_2" />

            <com.company.calculator.ButtonPlus
                android:id="@+id/button_dot"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:textSize="45sp"
                android:text="@string/button_dot"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_equals"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_3"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button_3"/>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But my XML layout design in Android Studio look like this:

[image: XML layout design in Android Studio]

So, please tell me where I am wrong & please help me to resolve this problem.
**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Your xml would help...

Comment: please add your xml file  code

Comment: please specify the device in which you are testing may be on some device it is looking like this ,you can use preview all screen sizes feature of android studio ,which will show the layout on all screen size and can identify issue.

Comment: which AppThem is used check on your styles.xml

Comment: @krunal patel theme is:Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Comment: @ss_android the device is redmi 2.

Comment: fine,can you please put xml code hear ?

Comment: @krunal patel i just posted it.

Comment: have you tried `weightSum`

Comment: @mohit can we use it in relative layout?

Comment: no you have use `LinearLayout`

Comment: or you can also use `TableLayout`

Comment: @Mohit no i had used relative layout in my xml

Answer (score 0):

i have not answer why this problem created but i have solution by this way try it.
    please put `color` of `Button` background like

```
 <Button  android:id="@+id/button_clear"
             android:layout_width="95dp"
             android:layout_height="80dp"
             android:background="#DCDDDD"
             android:text="C"
             android:textSize="25sp"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
```

try it.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting fixed values for height and width of your buttons. The emulator in Android Studio has enough space to represent them properly while respecting it, but your device looks like doesn't. To fit them properly, try to reduce the size of your button.

If you want the size of the buttons to adjust the size of every device's screen, you can get the size of the screen of the device this way:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics; 
int width = 0, height = 0;
metrics = new DisplayMetrics();        
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
height = metrics.heightPixels;     
width = metrics.widthPixels;
```

And do some calculations to programmatically set the size of your buttons.

Comment: Better off using weights in the xml. (imo)

Comment: @fustigador  can you provide me some links so that i can understand properly

Comment: Its not that hard. In metrics variable you have the dimensions of the device the app is running in. if you need to fit two buttons, you can set the width of every button to be width/2. If you need three buttons, it should be width/3 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer i just use in my xml file.

```
 style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"
```

And also change some settings of AVD manager. Thanks everyone for your contribution